# Need help in implementing conditional outputs using the fork() function

Tags: c++

- In the below program i'm trying to implement these conditions:
- I'm trying to only implement the first child process to print “hi”?
- and the root process to print “areyou”?
- and the final child process must exit from the system without doing anything?

  ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    using namespace std;

    pid_t pid1,pid2,pid3,pid4;
    int function(){                        
    pid1=fork(); 
    if(pid1>0)
    {
    cout << "hi" << getpid()<<" " << getppid()<< endl; /*first child process should print "hi"*/
    }
    pid2=fork();
    cout << "hell" << getpid()<<" " << getppid()<< endl;
    pid3=fork();
    cout << "how "  <<getpid() <<" "<<getppid() <<endl;
    pid4=fork();

    if(pid4>0){
    return 0;/* final child process should exit from the system with out doing anything*/                                      
              }
          else{
   cout << "areyou "<<getpid()<<" "<<getppid()<<endl; 
              }
          }

   int main() {

   /* and the root process should print  "are you"*/
      function();
     }
  ```

  -with if(pid1>0) i guess i tried to implement first child to output "hi" and i feel i'm lost in understanding how can i get only the root parent process to print "areyou", and how to control the last child to exit with out doing anything

Comment: How many process do you expect to have ? I count `16`... You probably want some  more `else` to distinguish child and parent.

Comment: @Jardo yes only using the 16 process should be fine i dont want to distinguish between child and parent but i want the first child to print hi and the root parent process of the program to print the "areyou"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like

```
void function()
{                        
    pid_t pid1, pid2, pid3, pid4;
    pid1 = fork(); 
    if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        // first child process should print "hi"
        cout << "hi " << getpid() << " " << getppid()<< endl;

    }
    pid2 = fork();
    cout << "hell " << getpid() <<" " << getppid() << endl;
    pid3 = fork();
    cout << "how "  << getpid() <<" "<<getppid() << endl;
    pid4 = fork(); // Mostly useless as only parent print something for this one

    if (pid1 == 0 && pid2 == 0 && pid3 == 0 && pid4 == 0){
        return; // final child process should exit from the system with out doing anything
    } else if (pid1 > 0 && pid2 > 0 && pid3 > 0 && pid4 > 0){
        cout << "areyou "<< getpid() << "  "<< getppid() << endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/JsyGC6)

Comment: thanks but could you please help me understand what are we trying to do with these last two lines:  else if (pid1 > 0 && pid2 > 0 && pid3 > 0 && pid4 > 0){
        cout << "areyou "<< getpid() << "  "<< getppid() << endl;
    }

Comment: At each `fork()`, you have a parent (`pidX > 0`) and a child (`pidX == 0`). So from your 16 (`2 * 2 * 2 * 2`) processes, the main parent is the one which is the parent of each `fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

> with if(pid1>0) i guess i tried to implement first child to output "hi"

No, it's the *parent* that gets a positive pid (on success), because it gets the process-id of the child it just forked, or -1 if the fork call fails. The child receives a return value of `0`.

What you want to do goes like this:

```
if(pid1 < 0)
{
    cout << "fork failed to create a child process."
}
else if (pid1 > 0) // Parent
{
     cout << "areyou";
}
else // child
{
     cout << "hi";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarifying the differences and how to differentiate between the parent and child process using the return type  well this will help me a lot